# Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Authentication Error

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, auth-request

I am trying to execute the Oracle cloud infrastructure rest API's from the postman application I have followed their document and made the setup but I am getting authentication errors. I need some information regarding the OCI herders.

Answer (score 1):

You can go quickly to https://www.postman.com/oracledevs/workspace/oracle-cloud-infrastructure-rest-apis/overview, fork the API you want, and start using it.

No need for complex manual steps.

For the credentials, Fork the "OCI Credentials" and input your data, as shown here:
[Oracle Cloud Infrastructure credentials for Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwtOC.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below post for details.

https://redthunder.blog/2019/07/10/calling-oci-apis-from-postman/

In short, you need to create public/private key pair and upload public key to OCI via console. and use private key on your client (Postman) to authenticate your requests.